# search mvc json jquery

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm having trouble with auto-search when I want to make two values

I want to search the store for product, please guide:

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult Search(string pr, string name, string model, string brand, string storename) {
    var s = _context.Products.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(pr) || a.Model.Contains(pr) || a.Brands.Name.Contains(pr)).Select(a => new {
        name = a.Name, model = a.Model, brand = a.Brands.Name
    }).Take(10);
    var storen = _context.Stores.Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith(pr)).Select(a => new {
        storename = a.Name
    });
    return Json(new {
        s,
        storen
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var kam;
    $("#CityName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/search",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    pr: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return [{
                            label: item.name + " " + item.model + " " + item.brand,
                            value: item.name + " " + item.model + " " + item.brand
                        }]
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "",
            results: ""
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: The jQuery problem This code returns one response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to combine both result sets to show into one Autocomplete widget. So for that, try to modify your code to look like this

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult Search(string pr) {
    var s = _context.Products.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(pr) || a.Model.Contains(pr) || a.Brands.Name.Contains(pr)).Take(10).Select(a => new {
        resultItem = a.Name + " " + a.Model + " " + a.Brands.Name
    }).ToList();

    var storen = _context.Stores.Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith(pr)).Select(a => new {
        resultItem = a.Name
    }).ToList();

    var returnList = s.Concat(storen).ToList();

    return Json(new {
        returnList
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This way your controller returns only one result set in json format.

**View**

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#CityName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Search",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    pr: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return [{
                            label: item.resultItem,
                            value: item.resultItem
                        }]
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "",
            results: ""
        }
    });
})
```

Note that I have changed the ajax request type to `GET` and label and value use the same `resultItem` field.

Comment: thank you
This code does not solve my problem
Please visit www.n11.com || www.bamilo.com || www.digikala.com
You see, of course, this is my smallest point

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of:

```
var storen = _context
   .Stores
   .Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith(pr))
   .Select(a => new { storename = a.Name });
```

Don't you want to use `Contains`, like in the first query ?

```
var storen = _context
   .Stores
   .Where(a => a.Name.Contains(pr))
   .Select(a => new { storename = a.Name });
```